CMake Configuration Issue in STM32 Project – Cannot Include Header File
Im new to working with CMake, and I could use some help figuring out what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the STM32 VS Code extension and I generated a new empty project using STM32Cube MX with CMake output. The empty project compiles fine, no issues there. However, after I added a new subfolder in Core called Modules, with two files: ModuleA.c and ModuleA.h, I ran into problems.
In my CMakeLists.txt, I included the new module like this:
# Add sources to executable
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
   Core/Modules/ModuleA.c
)

# Add include paths
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Core/Modules
)

Despite this, when I try to call a test function from ModuleA.c in main.c, and include it with #include ModuleA.h, the compiler gives me an error saying: No such file or directory #include "ModuleA.h"
What else do I need to modify to make this work?
Do I need to change anything in the settings.json file inside the .vscode folder when I add new files, or is it supposed to update automatically?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Core
│
├── Inc
│   └── main.h
│   └── stm32xx_hal_conf.h
│   └── stm32xx_it.h
│
├── Modules   //this folder I add
│   └── ModuleA.h
│   └── ModuleA.c
│
└── Src
    └── main.c
    └── stm32xx_hal_msp.c
    └── system_stm32l0xx.c

build Log:
[main] Building folder: /Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/build/Release 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /ST/STM32CubeCLT_1.15.1/CMake/bin/cmake.EXE --build /Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/build/Release --
[build] [1/3] Building C object CMakeFiles/Cmake_testing_3.dir/Core/Src/main.c.obj
[build] FAILED: CMakeFiles/Cmake_testing_3.dir/Core/Src/main.c.obj 
[build] /ST/STM32CubeCLT_1.15.1/GNU-tools-for-STM32/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -DSTM32L071xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -I/Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3Core/Modules -I/Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/cmake/stm32cubemx/../../Core/Inc -I/Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/cmake/stm32cubemx/../../Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I/Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/cmake/stm32cubemx/../../Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I/Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/cmake/stm32cubemx/../../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L0xx/Include -I/Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/cmake/stm32cubemx/../../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -mcpu=cortex-m0plus  -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Os -g0 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus  -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Os -g0 -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Cmake_testing_3.dir/Core/Src/main.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\Cmake_testing_3.dir\Core\Src\main.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/Cmake_testing_3.dir/Core/Src/main.c.obj -c /Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/Core/Src/main.c
[build] /Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/Core/Src/main.c:24:10: fatal error: ModuleA.h: No such file or directory
[build]    24 | #include "ModuleA.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] [2/3] Building C object CMakeFiles/Cmake_testing_3.dir/Core/Modules/ModuleA.c.obj
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: /ST/STM32CubeCLT_1.15.1/CMake/bin/cmake.EXE --build /Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3/build/Release -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.136
[build] Build finished with exit code 1 


Hi, just added build Log

Seems to be a missing / in -I/Cmake_Testing/Cmake_testing_3Core/Modules between Cmake_testing_3 and Core.

It works, Thank you!
